# positive eigenfunction on complete Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a complete(non-compact) Riemannian manifold. Consider the positive solution to the equation 
$$
\Delta u = u
$$
where $\Delta=\nabla_i \nabla_i$ is negative semi-definite. Is there any known relations if there are two positive solutions? For example, the surface case($n=2$) with negative curvature bounded from below. Thanks!

Comment: Is it consistent? If $\Delta$ is negatively semi-definite, the solution should be $\Delta u =- u$. 
Anyway, a possible approach is to show "eigenfunctions must change sign except the ones corresponding to the first eigenvalue" and "first eigenvalue is simple". Thus your two functions differ only by a constant. These two statements are true in many cases, but I am not sure whether they hold in your case or not.

Comment: The surface is non-compact and the general existence result can be found in

D. Fischer-Colbrie and R. Schoen. The Structure of Complete Stable Minimal Surfaces in 3-manifolds of Non-negative Scalar Curvature.\emph{Comm. Pure Appl. Math.}, $\textbf{XXXIII}$:199--211, 1980.